# ROS with Qt creator. New packages do not show up

Tags: ros, qtcreator

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am fairly new to ROS. I started using QtCreator as my IDE for ROS development. I followed the instructions from http://wiki.ros.org/IDEs#QtCreator.

My problem is that whenever I add a new package using `catkin_create_pkg` the newly added package do not show up in QtCreator. I also tried reloading CMakeList.txt file from QtCreator (the one at workspace level).

What am I doing wrongly.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/207036/ros-with-qt-creator.-new-packages-do-not-show-up/) by [mpkuse](https://answers.ros.org/users/22134/mpkuse/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2015-04-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know why it doesn't refresh the Project on a build, but if you reconfigure the project, it should show up. Go to "Projects" in the sidebar then to the "Build & Run" tab and hit the "Run CMake..." button under CMake next to Reconfigure project.

---

Originally posted by [thebyohazard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1483/thebyohazard/) with karma: 3562 on 2015-04-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1